# Java concurrency data structure

Tags: java, concurrency

I am working to solve interesting concurrent problem! Not sure if I understand it correctly since I am little bit confused.

[image]

For thread-safety I wanted to use `ConcurrentMap`

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal>();

public BigDecimal getPrice(String id){
    return concurrentHashMap.get(id);
} 

public void updatePrice(String id, BigDecimal newPrice){
    concurrentHashMap.put(id, newPrice);
}
```

1. Will that solution guarantee a thread safe read/write? Is ConcurrentMap is good choice for this type of problem?
2. If I write to key `"a"` will it lock the whole Map or writes to `"b"` key is available?
3. What does take following part of the task means? *If during the time taken to process price Pa1 the prices Pa2, Pa3, and Pa4 arrive, then the next price the application should process is Pa4 and all previous prices should be ignored.*  - Probably I am overcomplicating things but does that mean I should not store and cancel price update if new more recent price arrive? If yes, then how would implementation look like?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've seen this question before as a pre-interview programming question. If you can't do it by yourself maybe you're not right for the job.

Comment: @brain No offence buddy but OP is not looking for opinions on whether he is right for the job or not. Moreover he is not even asking solution, he has somethings in his mind and he is simply asking clarifications for 3 of his doubts.

Answer (score 0):

So you do not run into any deadlock situations try something like: Or implement your own flags to check if the resource is in use before attempting to use it.

```
public synchronized void updatePrice(String id, BigDecimal newPrice){
     concurrentHashMap.put(id, newPrice);
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping access to a ConcurrentHashMap in a synchronized method?

Answer (score 0):

1.`ConcurrentHashMap` is safe to use in mutithreading environment.

2. It will not lock the whole map. Most likely you'll be able to write `b` in parallel.
3. Thats the most interesting part and the problem itself.
   Assume your `updatePrice` function perform some computation before storing. So new prices arrive and arrive but you slowly store one by one... And the queue of prices increase and increase....

*You have to read all the prices for specific key from the input  - discard Firsts and take only last one.*
If you say that your `hashMap` is in the middle. Before real *processing* you've be right. And thats like solve the problem.

`But!`  If prices come to often, each update will generate new object in memory heap (eden space). Your GC will die cleaning all this prices from the heap. So, what is interesting to do - is to understand if you can subscribe to different prices in different processors and: *read them all \ take the last*

Comment: Thanks! If I start simple and store all incoming price updates in the queue, do you think its reasonably efficient? Do I really need a queue if I am interested only in latest data, can I just use second concurrent map to store only latest update?

Comment: I mean `ConcurrentHashMap`  killing all complexity of the task. :) You'll always have latest update here... But yes - with HashMap the task seems to be resolved no need of extra queues.

Answer (score 0):

> Will that solution guarantee a thread safe read/write? Is
>   ConcurrentMap is good choice for this type of problem?

`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe implementation of `HashMap`, so using it will ensure thread safety. But keep in mind:

- Even though all operations are thread-safe, **retrieval operations do not entail locking**, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access
- Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). **Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations** holding upon their onset.

Read [Java doc of CHM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for more info.

> If I write to key "a" will it lock the whole Map or writes to "b" key
>   is available?

Yes, it will lock the map for any write operation and writes to "b" will not be available if write to "a" is in progress, but map will still be non-blocking for reads.

> What does take following part of the task means? If during the time
>   taken to process price Pa1 the prices Pa2, Pa3, and Pa4 arrive, then
>   the next price the application should process is Pa4 and all previous
>   prices should be ignored. - Probably I am overcomplicating things but
>   does that mean I should not store and cancel price update if new more
>   recent price arrive? If yes, then how would implementation look like?

This simply means that "**consider the latest price**".

Your choice of using a Map is good option considering the requirement because when you will use `hashMap.put("pa", 123)` then it will discard the previous value, so whenever you are reading the hashmap, you will always read the latest value.

You may want to use simple `HashMap`, if there is really no need to implement concurrency. Concurrency should be requirement but not choice.

Comment: Thats's not true. `Put` operation does not block whole map for update! Read the documentation `... supporting full concurrency of retrievals and
 * _high expected concurrency for updates._`

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that if I write to key `"a"` key `"b"` will be blocked for writes as well? One of the requirements is to keep `"b"` accessible. I read somewhere that it locks a bucket but not a key, does that mean it not guaranteed to be locked or assessable, depends on the bucket of your key?

Comment: What do you understand by "*adjustable expected concurrency for updates.*", may be you are misinterpreting. Check the `ConcurrentHashMap` and will find that there is lock and unlock code for `put`.

Comment: @WildGoat Yes, it will. That's why I said choice of Map is good but I am not sure why you need concurrency there. As per the problem statement I don't see any concurrency requirement. You may want to use simple `HashMap`.

Comment: @hagrawal, what would be the best data structure if I need guarantee thread-safe and concurrent access to update and get prices for the same or different keys, since prices may be update and accessed by multiple threads.

Comment: "*guarantee thread-safe and concurrent access to update*" - if something is thread safe then it means that no 2 thread can access it same time which basically means "no concurrency". So, what you are asking is contradicting. A data structure is a container and is treated as a whole, so you cannot divide that this much part is open for concurrency and this much is not.

Comment: Looking at what you want, you can consider using Integer (with synchronization), where one integer is assigned to one price category, for example Integers like priceA, priceB etc. But you need to think if there are many prices then it will not be good approach and then you have to use a DS. If there are not many price categories then you can use it because all you need is latest price, so thread will override the value and in the end whenever you will read it you will have latest value.

Comment: Any news ?? Does it answer your 3 questions ?? Please let me know if you hv any other question ..